# How can I open webview when user click in "quick replies" button?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-messenger-bot

Is it possible to open webview when user click in "quick replies" button ?

```
quick_replies: [
        {
          content_type:"text",
          title:"Notifications",
          payload:"notifyme",          
        },
        {
          content_type:"text",
          title:"Favoris",
          payload:"favoris",
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. The webview can only be opened from URL button, a messenger extension, or the persistent menu. Maybe consider using the list template instead of quick reply if that's the functionality you need.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/showing#entry